# Print an array of strings and ignore nulls

Tags: c

I have four array of strings. I would like to print out the strings with this formatting:

```
                        printf(" %d \t %s \t %s \t %s \t %s.\n",
                        quadruples_line_counter,
                        strings_quadruples1_action[0],
                        strings_quadruples2_variable1[0],
                        strings_quadruples3_variable2[0],
                        strings_quadruples4_temp_variable[0]);
```

It gives this output:

```
17      func    sub     int     3.
 17      param   (null)          (null)          (null).
 17      alloc           4       (null)          xa.
 17      alloc           4       (null)          y.
 17      alloc           4       (null)          z.
 17      multiply        55      y       t0.
 17      divide          t0      z       t1.
 17      plus            xa      t1      t2.
 17      plus            t2      x       t3.
 17      func    main    void    0.
 17      alloc           4       (null)          a.
 17      alloc           4       (null)          b.
 17      alloc           4       (null)          c.
 17      arg             (null)          (null)          x.
 17      arg             (null)          (null)          y.
 17      arg             (null)          (null)          z.
 17      call            sub     3       t5.
 17      assign          t5      (null)          y.
```

How would I go about ignoring the nulls when printing? I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: `strings_quadruples1_action[0] == NULL ? `strings_quadruples1_action[0] : ""`

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to use the ternary operator :

```
strings_quadruples1_action[0]!=NULL?strings_quadruples1_action[0]:""
```

Do the same for other three strings as well.

Or define a macro in the beginning :

```
#define NO_NULL(X) X!=NULL?X:""
```

and do printf like :

```
printf(" %d \t %s \t %s \t %s \t %s.\n",
                        quadruples_line_counter,
                        NO_NULL(strings_quadruples1_action[0]),
                        NO_NULL(strings_quadruples2_variable1[0]),
                        NO_NULL(strings_quadruples3_variable2[0]),
                        NO_NULL(strings_quadruples4_temp_variable[0]));
```